# grid_remove() работа с чат-ботом

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Мне нужно что бы стирался label
код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
root= Tk()
root.title("Чат - бот")
root.geometry("400x500")
def chat():
    name = ttk.Label(root,text = "Пообщайся с ботом)")
    name.grid(column = 50)
    chatx = Entry(root,width = 40)
    chatx.grid(row = 40,column=10,columnspan = 70)
    ot = ttk.Button(root,text = "Отправить",width = 10,command=lambda: otvet())
    ot.grid(row = 40,column=90,columnspan = 70,)
    def otvet():
        if chatx.get().lower() == "привет":


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Привет")

            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)


        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты джеймс!":
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')



            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: ты угадал")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        if chatx.get().lower() == "выйди за меня":
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')

            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: прости,но у меня есть масса других потенциальных женихов")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты красивая?":
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')

            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Эм")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты голодная?":



            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Нет,я не сильно то люблю есть...")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "что делаешь?":


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: рисую процессор на системном блоке")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "как дела?":

            sir.grid_remove()
            sir.update()
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: супер")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        else:


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sirk = ttk.Label (root, text="Siri: мой словарный запас мал...")
            sirk.grid(columnspan=700)
chat()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: P.s в sir.grid_remove() и sir.update() написан во всех вариантов,просто скинул старую версию

Answer (score 0):

Очень много говнокода, можно было всё умесить в 20 строчках, тут мне в голову ничего не лезет кроме как изменять предыдущие ответы через `configure()` метод, виджета label.

Comment: Я хотел в этом убедиться,в этом варианте намного легче просто через классы всё сделать и не морочить голову